# API-Platform 2 -- joined entity does not show data, but url to that data instead

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities joined one to many. When I call the API for it, I get collection as the referencing url and not the entente data itself.

What do I need to have in my entity annotation to get that data collected? Here is the output from API client:

```
  {
    "@id": "/app_dev.php/api/fee_schedule_categories/4",
    "@type": "FeeScheduleCategory",
    "id": 4,
    "custId": 0,
    "scheduleName": "Daily Claim Schedule",
    "scheduleStatus": 1,
    "scheduleId": [
      "/app_dev.php/api/fee_schedules/1239",
      "/app_dev.php/api/fee_schedules/1240",
      "/app_dev.php/api/fee_schedules/1241",
      "/app_dev.php/api/fee_schedules/1242"
    ],
    }
```

`scheduleId` should show data and not API links.

Here are my entities:

`AppBundle/Entity/FeeSchedule.php`

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ApiResource
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class FeeSchedule
    {
        /**
         * @var int The id of fee category tier.
         *
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var FeeScheduleCategory The fee schedule category this fee schedule tier is for.
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FeeScheduleCategory",inversedBy="schedule_id")
         */
        private $schedule_category;

        /**
         * @var decimal.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
         */
        private $range_from;

        /**
         * @var decimal.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
         */
        private $range_to;

        /**
         * @var decimal.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
         */
        private $amount;

        /**
         * @var int.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $amount_type;
```

`AppBundle/Entity/FeeScheduleCategory.php`

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ApiResource
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class FeeScheduleCategory
    {
        /**
         * @var int The id of this fee schedule category.
         *
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var ArrayCollection<\AppBundle\Entity\FeeSchedule> Available fee schedules.
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeeSchedule", mappedBy="schedule_category")
         */
        private $schedule_id;

        /**
         * @var int The customer id of this this fee schedule category.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $cust_id;

        /**
         * @var string The title of this schedule category.
         *
         * @ORM\Column
         */
        private $schedule_name;

        /**
         * @var int The enabled/disabled status.
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $schedule_status;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->schedule_id = new ArrayCollection();
        }
```

Comment: We probably need to see your API controller and how it's returning the `scheduleId` array.

Comment: I'm using API-plaform 2 bundle so the code above is the only code I write, controller comes from the bundle itself, but I just got the answer and it is here for anyone that wonders. Yes it's possible using serialization groups: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization-groups-and-relations#embedding-relations

Answer (score 0):

By default, API Platform serializes all relations as links (IRIs). If you want to embed the related document instead, you need to use groups as described in the documentation: [Embedding Relations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations).

For your code, it will look like the following:

`FeeScheduleCategory.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 *  @ApiResource(attributes={"normalization_context"={"groups"={"fsc_read"}}})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FeeScheduleCategory
{
    /**
     * @var int The id of this fee schedule category.
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection<\AppBundle\Entity\FeeSchedule> Available fee schedules.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeeSchedule", mappedBy="schedule_category")
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $schedule_id;

    /**
     * @var int The customer id of this this fee schedule category.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $cust_id;

    /**
     * @var string The title of this schedule category.
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $schedule_name;

    /**
     * @var int The enabled/disabled status.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $schedule_status;

    // ...
}
```

`FeeSchedule.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FeeSchedule
{
    /**
     * @var int The id of fee category tier.
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var FeeScheduleCategory The fee schedule category this fee schedule tier is for.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FeeScheduleCategory",inversedBy="schedule_id")
     */
    private $schedule_category;

    /**
     * @var decimal.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $range_from;

    /**
     * @var decimal.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $range_to;

    /**
     * @var decimal.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=13, scale=2)
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var int.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"fsc_read"})
     */
    private $amount_type;

    // ...
}
```